# How can I use a Python script to get the transformation of an object?

Tags: python, objects, coordinates

How can I use a Python script to obtain the exact coordinates of an object?

I have not been able to find out how to do this in the documentation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Background:** The object location (in fact transformation - so location/scale/rotation) is defined by initial values which are used to calculate the final transformation.

- initial transform (as set by the user and possibly set by animation *FCurves* and *Drivers*).
  *as a tool author, to manipulate data this is what you'll want to access typically*
- final transform (with parenting, constraints, and rigid body physics applied).
  *when writing exporters or reading, typically this is what you will want to access since its whats displayed in the view (but you can't directly manipulate it)*

To get the input location you can simply do:

`loc = bpy.context.object.location`... or via its matrix
`bpy.context.object.matrix_local.to_translation()`

To get the output transformation you can only do this by accessing the worldspace matrix.

`loc = bpy.context.object.matrix_world.to_translation()`

You may want to get the loc/rotation/scale, in that case:

`loc, rot, scale = bpy.context.object.matrix_world.decompose()`

---

If you want to test the location for example, you can set the cursor position.

```
from bpy import context
context.scene.cursor_location = context.object.matrix_world.to_translation()
```

Or you can create a new empty:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Empty", None)
context.scene.objects.link(obj)
obj.matrix_world  = context.object.matrix_world
```

... note, if the matrix contains shear, you wont see this in the empty, for that try the [MathVis](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Math_Viz) addons.

Comment: What would be the best way for me to test the above code? The Blender-Python integration tutorials I have completed have been based around graphical results.

Comment: Added notes on viewing the transformation.